# npm start issues with react

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I get this error when I start npm.Please help me on this error.

> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

```
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/s'←[39m, ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'"http://localhost:3000"'←[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! codevolution@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the codevolution@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RAJESH 1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-13T03_49_58_367Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like node.js can't find **cmd** trying so spawn a new process, so you need to add **cmd** to your **path**